# How to write a test as a method in Go?

Tags: go

I have a below test:

```
package api_app

func (api *ApiResource) TestAuthenticate(t *testing.T) {
    httpReq, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/login", nil)
    req := restful.NewRequest(httpReq)

    recorder := new(httptest.ResponseRecorder)
    resp := restful.NewResponse(recorder)

    api.Authenticate(req, resp)
    if recorder.Code!= 404 {
        t.Logf("Missing or wrong status code:%d", recorder.Code)
    }
}
```

I want to test this function but when I do

`go test api_app -v`

The test never rungs this. I understand that's because I have receiver for the function.

Is there a way we can test this thing?

Comment: Why not use `http.Transport{}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [testing package](http://godoc.org/testing) works with functions, not methods.  Write a function wrapper to test the method:

```
func TestAuthenticate(t *testing.T) {
   api := &ApiResource{} // <-- initialize api as appropriate.
   api.TestAuthenticate(t)
}
```

You can move all of the code to the test function and eliminate the method:

```
func TestAuthenticate(t *testing.T) {
    api := &ApiResource{} // <-- initialize api as appropriate.
    httpReq, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/login", nil)
    req := restful.NewRequest(httpReq)

    recorder := new(httptest.ResponseRecorder)
    resp := restful.NewResponse(recorder)

    api.Authenticate(req, resp)
    if recorder.Code!= 404 {
        t.Logf("Missing or wrong status code:%d", recorder.Code)
    }
}
```

Comment: The errors are a separate question. You ought to accept this answer and ask a new one.

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper The test runs and fails as indicated by the first couple of lines of output. There's insufficient information to diagnose why the test fails. Perhaps ask a new question as suggested by Christopher?